# CodeIgniter - How Do I Rewrite URLs with URL Parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, codeigniter

I need to turn URL's such as the following:

```
/catalog/products/24
```

into cleaner URL's such as the following:

```
/catalog/product-name-here
```

I'm using CodeIgniter, and rewrite engine is on and setup. I also setup rewriting in the `routes.php` file as follows:

```
$route['catalog/products/(:any)'] = 'catalog/view/$1';
```

**Question**: Where do I replace the product ID `/24` with `/product-name-here`? I can successfully get the parameter `$1`, and fetch the product name. I can't seem to figure out how to rewrite the URL with this dynamic value though. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a codeigniter user but I smell that URL rewriting is not the best place to achieve this.

You still need to write a controller method that can identify a product using something like slug='product-name-here' instead of id=24.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the products name as a URL slug into your product row in the database table. Good practice for that the `url_title()` method from the **URL Helper**.

Then you just have to search for the slug from your database in your code, rather than the id.

So this is just a hint because I don't have the time right now. But if you've got questions, ask it here, I will come back to answer it.

And sorry for my poor English! :)